# Div with text over <hr> line

Tags: html, css

How I can do this effect with `<hr>`? Div with content will be over `<hr>`. How to do that?

[image: Hr line with text in image]

This is my jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/fnaYs/. I don't know how to put this text into image box. Any solutions?

After, I want to add this layout to wordpress, so I want put text in `<div>` or another element, not in css file.

Comment: Something like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/fnaYs/5/ - you need to be more specific with your requirements as this does have some limitations depending on the content of the `<div>`

Comment: Everyone is giving the same position:absolute solutions and I dont know who, someone seems to be down voting those answers. Weird

Comment: @G.Z i was about to give a solution using z-index. Then i saw Adrift has posted a fiddle. Check that.

Comment: @Ali Gajani It's not me. Thanks a lot for answers. Adrift helped me.

Comment: With curiosity - is it possible to do that same think (Box with the text which I can change) with `:after:` and `:before` and element `content` as in my `jsfiddle`? (without using div)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set the `position` attribute of a variable to `relative`, it basically means that the position of the element is relative to the browser.

So when you say `top:-5px;` it means you are requesting the browser to put your element 5 pixels above the position where it actually is supposed to be..

All you have to do is, set the top attribute for the div, in CSS to some negative value. like this:

```
<hr />
<div style="position:relative;top:-5px;">DIV CONTENT</div>
```

Replace the `-5px` with your requirement...

Answer (score 1):

I have coded a solution (there might be other ways).

Here is a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fnaYs/6/

**CSS**

```
hr.line {
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
}

.box {
    background-color:teal;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    left: 40%;
    bottom:90%;
    padding-top:20px;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<hr class="line"/>
<div class="box"> Text </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution does not match the OP's requirement. He wants the box on the line, not under it.

Comment: Weird, it is on the line bud? Check my image in the new edit.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 28.0.1500.95 m: http://i.imgur.com/Q9TZ8wj.png It doesn't work with Firefox Aurora 25.0a2 either. It yields the same result.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a working jsFiddle with what you need:
http://jsfiddle.net/2LaLb/

`<hr class="line" />
<div class="mydiv">Div with text</div>`

and the corresponding CSS would be:

```
    hr.line {
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
}

    .mydiv {
background:red;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:400px;
}
```

As you can see it produces the result you want.